# How to launch Camera app from Unity in android?

Tags: c#, android, android-studio, unity-game-engine, android-intent

I want to launch camera app in android from Unity3d app. I can do it by building an Android app through Android Studio. I want to create a jar plugin of that android studio project and call the code through Unity game.

Unity C# code

```
public class UnityAndroidPluginExample : MonoBehaviour
{
    AndroidJavaObject javaClass;

    public void CallPlugin()
    {
        javaClass = new AndroidJavaObject("com.mycompany.pluginexample.CameraPluginClass");
        javaClass.Call("LaunchCameraApp");
    }
}
```

Android Studio Code

```
package com.mycompany.pluginexample;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class CameraPluginClass extends AppCompatActivity
{
    public void LaunchCameraApp()
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

I am getting error

> AndroidJavaException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:com.mycompany.pluginexample.CameraPluginClass
>
> AndroidJavaException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:Failed resolution of: Landroidx/appcompat/app/AppCompatActivity

Here is my Android Studio code that worked for Android

```
    btnCaptureImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        }
    });
```

Please help, I am stuck here. In short, I cannot call a method of the Java class that extends AppCompatACtivity. If I remove `extends AppCompatActivity` and call a method in that Java Class from Unity, it works, only if I use `extends AppCompatActivty`, I cannot call any method inside that class from Unity. I am using Unity version 2019.1.7f1.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is your unity version?

Comment: @0xBFE1A8, I am using Unity Version 2019.1.7f1.

Answer (score 0):

Changing "AppCompatActivity" to just "Activity" worked for me, though I'm not sure why. If you ever figure out why, let me know!